# Element wise maximum (and minimum) of multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Using the [numpy.maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) function I can get the element wise maximum of two arrays in python.

for example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,1]

print(np.maximum(a, b))
```

results in: `[2 3 3]`

How can I do the same with three, four or n arrays?

for example, for the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,1]
c = [3,2,1]
```

I want a function to return `[3 3 3]`

Comment: Example data would be good for clarity and testing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is an example for four array

```
A = np.array([0,1,2])
B = np.array([1,0,3])
C = np.array([3,0,4])
D = np.array([7,0,4])
print(np.maximum.reduce([A,B,C,D]))
```

for n array `np.maximum.reduce([A,B,C,D,......,n])`

Answer (score 3):

To keep the maximum element of each location in the array, you can turn the arrays into a matrix and then grab the column max:

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,1]
c = [3,2,1]

arr = np.array([a,b,c])


print(arr.max(axis=0))
```